# How can I write a loop shell script by including a NCO statement in the loop for each files, and then make a new NetCDF file after all process

Tags: shell

How to apply the below command for multiple netcdf file, let say! I have daily netcdf files

```
glo12_rg_1h-m_20210201.nc 
glo12_rg_1h-m_20210202.nc
glo12_rg_1h-m_20210203.nc
....
....
....
....
glo12_rg_1h-m_20210226.nc
glo12_rg_1h-m_20210227.nc
glo12_rg_1h-m_20210228.nc
```

I want to apply for each in a shell script in a loop the commands below sequence. And then creation of a new netcdf file after all process on '.nc' files. I really appreciate anyone can help me how to do it.

```
ncks -O -x -v vo,uo,zos  glo12_rg_1h-m_20210201.nc data_01_output1.nc 
rm glo12_rg_1h-m_20210201.nc
#
ncra -F -d time,1,24 data_01_output1.nc data_01_output2.nc
rm data_01_output1.nc
#
ncrename -O -d depth,z -d longitude,x -d latitude,y -d time,time_counter data_01_output2.nc   data_01_output3.nc
rm data_01_output2.nc
```

I am trying the below command to do but setting and reading time for each '.nc' files in a loop for me is a little tricky

```
for fl in `ls *.nc` ; do
   ncks -O -x -v vo,uo,zos  glo12_rg_1h-m_20210201.nc data_01_output1.nc  ${fl}
   rm glo12_rg_1h-m_20210201.nc  ${fl}
   #
   ncra -F -d time,1,24 data_01_output1.nc data_01_output2.nc ${fl}
   rm data_01_output1.nc ${fl}
   #
   ncrename -O -d depth,z -d longitude,x -d latitude,y -d time,time_counter data_01_output2.nc               data_01_output3.nc ${fl}
   rm data_01_output2.nc ${fl}
done
```

Comment: 1) Until you get this working, I recommend instead of `rm ...` you `/bin/mv glo12_rg_1h-m_20210201.nc /path/to/archive/$(date +%Y/%m/%d)`. What happens if you have an error during your development, you will want to reprocess those files until you get it right (for months or a year (-;! ). 2) based on your example runs in the first section of code, I think you want to have `ncks -O -x -v vo,uo,zos    "${fl}" data_01_output1.nc`. 3) always fix syntax issues flagged when you paste code to https://shellcheck.net. Besure to include `#!/bin/bash` as the first line. ....

Comment: 4) you can just do `for fl in *.nc; do` you don't need `$( ls ..)`. As mentioned in `1)` (above), you seem to have a lot of extra stuff where just replacing `glo12_rg_1h-m_20210201.nc` with `"${fl}"` will solve most of your problems. Learn to read the output of the shell debug/trace that you set at the top with `set -vx` (and turn off with `set +vx`) and then carefully examine the cmd, it's options , and any variable substitutions (`${fl}"` , etc). Make sure they are in the same order asy your example code in the first block above. Good luck!

Comment: Dear shellter, thanks for your reply. I would like to save the '.nc' data corresponding to each file sorted by date $m$d after making changes to it in a new '.nc' file with the corresponding time prefix. e.g.,    glo12_rg_1h-m_20210201.nc     ---save after removing variables into --- data_01.nc,     glo12_rg_1h-m_20210202.nc  ---into---data_02.nc, ...etc

Comment: learn to experiment with sample code. I'm assuming you're not sure how to use the `date` command? Just go the the cmd line and copy/paste just the `date +...` from my sample above. If you don't like my date format, then edit the `+...` specification string. Read `man date` (it is a lot, but if you want to get good at script writing `man` is your quickest friend). Else Google, else post here. Busy now. let me know how you are getting along. we can't really do coaching in comments. Try posting a "hello" message to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98569/bin-bash . Good luck.

Comment: I have only 3 netcdf files and the first one is supposed to be the first day and the third one is the last day, but I don't know the below command,
last_day=`echo $(ls -1 | wc -l)` 
it counts four days when running inside the loop. for kf in *.nc; do
  last_day=`echo $(ls -1 | wc -l)`    
  for ((i=1;i<$last_day;i++)); do
    ival='0'${i}
    kval=$kf
done 
done

Comment: look at just the output from `ls -1` Where/what is the extra file?

Comment: I can try and help for a while today. I recommend you add a section at the bottom labeled **`edit`**. Include your "best" attempt using above comment code to show your status with the problem. Good luck.